# Amazon Cloudfront can't connect after moving to new server

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I just moved my Magento site from one server to another host/server. Everything works except for Cloudfront. The new server DOES have SSL, just like the last server did.

But now when I try to view anything from Cloudfront I get the error:

"CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin."

Is like the DNS cached at Amazon and taking them forever to update it? Is there something you need to do when moving a site to a new server to keep CloudFront working?

Comment: It seems like there are a number of obvious troubleshooting steps you should try, not the least of which would be to try http from cloudfront to the origin (what if your ssl is not fully correct? "It works from a browser" proves very little.)  Point a new, test hostname to the new server, and point cloudfront to the new hostname (this rules out a dns issue).  Check your server logs for connection attempts from cf?  Try these things with a totally new cf distribution? (Without removing the old one. Setting up a new distribution is free.)

Comment: Is your SSL  configuration on your new server the same as your old?

Doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#RequestCustomEncryption

Answer (score 1):

Making CloudFront work with SSL can be tricky, specifically when the hostname of the origin is different from the hostname of the CNAME. 
For example, if your hostname is www.example.com, and the origin is www-example.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com, the request from the cloudfront server will contain a Host header of the origin :

```
> GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: www-example.us-west.elasticbeanstalk.com
> User-Agent: CloudFront/2.3
> Accept: */*
```

The origin host needs to be able to handle authenticated SSL requests for www-example.us-west.elasticbeanstalk.com, but usually you set it up in such way that it can handle SSL requests for the original hostname, www.example.com. In which case you have two options :

1. Whitelist the Host header. This will cause CloudFront to send the same Host header ( Host: www.example.com ) to the origin, which should be able to handle it correctly :
   [image]
2. Another option is to set your origin to be the same hostname with a different subdomain, for example set the origin as origin.example.com and set a CNAME between origin.example.com and  www-example.us-west.elasticbeanstalk.com